# Buscaminas no busca camino alternativo

Tags: java

Me han pedido en la escuela hacer un "Buscaminas" todo medianamente bien, hasta que el programa debe buscar espacios vacíos... (no miren las preguntas de abajo, eso en parte lo solucione)[image: Se supone que debería hacer esto]

Según la posición dada por el usuario por defecto sube, da una vuelta siguiendo el sentido del reloj si es que no puede seguir avanzando por dicho camino, una vez ha girado 4 veces seguidas en el mismo punto, este debería volverse según la dirección por la que avanzo (si subió, baja, si fue a la izq., va a la derecha, así sucesivamente) pero antes de volverse una segunda vez debería buscar si hay otro camino disponible tal como lo muestra la imagen de arriba.

El problemas es...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que no busca caminos alternativos. El error esta en el siguiente código:

```
static void Busqueda(int X, int Y) {
        try {
            int i = X, j = Y, PAX = i, PAY = j, Direccion = 1, CG = 0;//PA=Posicion Actual
            //1 UP, 2 RIGHT, 3 DOWN, 4 LEFT
            //CG=Contador de Giros
            boolean Escaneando, Retorno = false;
            String Camino = "";
            do {
                do {
                    Escaneando = true;
                    switch (Direccion) {
                        case 1:
                            if (i - 1 >= 0) {
                                i--;
                                Escaneando = false;
                            } else {
                                Direccion = 2;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (j + 1 <= Columnas - 1) {
                                j++;
                                Escaneando = false;
                            } else {
                                Direccion = 3;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if (i + 1 <= Filas - 1) {
                                i++;
                                Escaneando = false;
                            } else {
                                Direccion = 4;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            if (j - 1 >= 0) {
                                j--;
                                Escaneando = false;
                            } else {
                                Direccion = 1;
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            Direccion = 1;
                            break;
                    }
                } while (Escaneando);
                if (Tableros[i][j][0] != '?') {
                    System.out.println("Segundo");
                    i = PAX;
                    j = PAY;
                    Direccion++;
                    CG++;
                    if (Direccion > 4) {
                        Direccion = 1;
                    }
                    if (CG > 4) {
                        CG = 0;
                        if (Camino.length() > 1) {
                            Camino = Camino.substring(0, Camino.length() - 1);
                        } else if (Camino.length() == 1) {
                            Camino = "";
                        } else {
                            Retorno = true;
                        }

                    }
                } else {
                    Tableros[i][j][0] = Tableros[i][j][1];
                    if (Tableros[i][j][0] != ' ') {
                        i = PAX;
                        j = PAY;
                        Direccion++;
                    } else {
                        Camino = Camino + Direccion;
                    }
                }
            } while (!Retorno);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage() + " Busqueda");
        }

    }
```

Edit: Actualmente el código avanza y recorre el camino girando a la izquierda o derecha, pero cuando llega a un tope (en este punto se empieza a volver) no vuelve a analizar el camino a su alrededor (tendría que buscar si existe otra ruta disponible).

En el caso de arriba el programa empieza en la posición 7-5(6-4 en matriz) y por un pequeño error de calculo avanzo de mas pero, el hecho es de que gira, pero cuando llega a un limite este no busca nuevo camino, por ejemplo en la imagen el limite fue la posición 7-4(6-3 de la matriz) pero no busco otro camino alterno, el programa cuando empieza a volverse debería buscar otro símbolo '?' en la matriz Tableros[X][X][0], una vez detectado continuar su camino por el mismo (el nuevo camino encontrado)

PD: Uh tampoco giro como debía en la ultima por el error de calculo que se corrigió después, pero aun sigue sin buscar un camino alterno, y no, no se el funcionamiento de pilas

Comment: Este ejercicio no lo veo como nivel de escuela.... te han enseñado pilas?

Comment: El problema se entiende, pero no especificas que es lo que hace actualmente tu código vs lo que debería hacer. Podrías poner un ejemplo en particular de qué hace vs lo uque debería hacer?

Comment: @Yussef aun no me han enseñado pilas ¿y de que nivel lo vez? (Para comentarlo con el profesor)

Comment: @BrunoTheFox Lo veo algo avanzado, pero quizás yo estoy entendiendo mal el problema. Hay unos elementos que se llaman GRAFOS, los cuales tienen nodos cada nodo vendría a ser un celda en tu problema. Hay algoritmos para recorrer grafos, uno de ellos se llama búsqueda en profundidad. Para implementarlo necesitas una Pila, una lista y un while; o usar recursividad (que es más enredado)

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el problema que tenia resulta que estaba trabajando con las variables equivocadas al momento de hacer la vuelta, todo este tiempo creí que el programa no escaneaba el alrededor, cuando lo que hacia era que no se volvía, adjunto el arreglo que hice abajo

Nota: Los System.out.println() están solo para verificar como reacciona el programa, estos pueden ser eliminados o comentados por cualquier adversidad

```
if (Tableros[i][j][0] != '?') {
                    System.out.println("Segundo");
                    i = PAX;
                    j = PAY;
                    Direccion++;
                    CG++;
                    if (Direccion > 4) {
                        Direccion = 1;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Direccion " + Direccion + "\nCG " + CG);
                    System.out.println("i=" + i + " j=" + j);
                    System.out.println("PAX="+PAX+" PAY="+PAY);
                    if (CG > 4) {
                        CG = 0;
                        System.out.println("Camino="+Camino);
                        if (Camino.length() > 1) {
                            switch (Camino.charAt(Camino.length() - 1)) {
                                case '1':PAX++;i=PAX;j=PAY;
                                    break;
                                case '2':PAY--;i=PAX;j=PAY;
                                    break;
                                case '3':PAX--;i=PAX;j=PAY;
                                    break;
                                case '4':PAY++;i=PAX;j=PAY;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    CG=4;Camino=Camino+Camino.charAt(Camino.length()-1);
                                    break;
                            }
                            Camino = Camino.substring(0, Camino.length() - 1);

                        } else if (Camino.length() == 1) {
                            switch (Camino.charAt(0)) {
                                case '1':PAX++;i=PAX;j=PAY;
                                    break;
                                case '2':PAY--;i=PAX;j=PAY;
                                    break;
                                case '3':PAX--;i=PAX;j=PAY;
                                    break;
                                case '4':PAY++;i=PAX;j=PAY;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    CG=4;Camino=Camino+Camino;
                                    break;
                            }
                            Camino = "";
                        } else {
                            Retorno = true;
                        }

                    }
                }
```